# Why I can't use an emit function in Kotlin Flow like rxJava.Single.create?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to rewrite interactors with rxjava chains to kotlin flow. In LocationHandlerImpl I'm using LocationService for getting my current location. In addOnSuccessListener and addOnFailureListener I'm emitting my model but having error:

[image: emit]

"Suspension function can be called only within coroutine body". Am i doing it wrong? But i can call emit outside of listeners (look below flow builder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned from Prokash ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58990380/3330058)), Flows are designed to be self contained. Your location services listener is not within the scope of the Flow.

You can however check out the `callbackFlow` which provides you the mechanics you are looking for to build a flow using a Callback-based API.

[Callback Flow Documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html), be aware that the callback flow is still in Experimental phase.

Comment: it worked for me. The error disappeared, I had to add an annotation about experimental api

Comment: @IliyaMashin did the callbackFlow worked for you? If yes, you can mark the correct answer so your question is marked as solved.

Comment: it didn't. compile error disappears but i had new exception ClosedSendChannelException at runtime. when i called offer(T)

Comment: Can you post some actual code snippets on the current state of your code? It will help us a lot.

Comment: sorry. it was my mistake. i just forgot about "awaitClose". it works but i can't enter to onCompletion block

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you are trying to get the last location from the Android location service. This is one of many `Task`-returning calls in the Google Play Services. Kotlin already has a module, [`kotlinx-coroutines-play-services`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/index.html), that contributes a function

```
suspend fun <T> Task<T>.await(): T?
```

With that in your project, you can simply write this:

```
suspend fun getMyLocation(): Location? =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProvider(context)
                .lastLocation
                .await()
```

If you want to integrate it with other `Flow`-based code, add this wrapper function:

```
fun <T> Task<T>.asFlow() = flow { emit(await()) }
```

and now you can write

```
fun getLocationAsFlow(): Flow<Location?> =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProvider(context)
                .lastLocation
                .asFlow()
```

If, for educational purposes, you would like to see how it can be implemented directly, without the additional module, then the most straightforward approach would be as follows:

```
fun getLocationAsFlow() = flow {
    val location = suspendCancellableCoroutine<Location?> { cont ->
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProvider(context)
                .lastLocation
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    val e = exception
                    when {
                        e != null -> cont.resumeWithException(e)
                        isCanceled -> cont.cancel()
                        else -> cont.resume(result)
                    }
                }
    }
    emit(location)
}
```

This is the result of inlining a simplified implementation of `Task.await()` into its use site.

Comment: Why does it need to be `suspend` function?

Comment: For context, you were referring to `getLocationAsFlow()`, which doesn't have to be suspendable. Removed.